# use metamask to send eth to many adresses

Tags: solidity, mist, myetherwallet, metamask

i want to use metamask / myetherwallet  and not mist because of sync problemems to send token to 100 addresse

i have this code (solidity) but i dont know how to implement it

please help me

link to the code : https://pastebin.com/hjKmsMp8

[image]

Comment: That code looks like it would assist sending _tokens_ to a bunch of recipients, but it wouldn't work to send ether.

Comment: yes i want to send tokens / but how to do it / whats the process, can you explain pleaaase, its important, thank you

Answer (score -1):

Follow the steps below.

1. Ensure you have metamask installed, logged in, the account is loaded and chosen (i.e., address from where you deployed the contract of airdrop).
2. Open http://remix.ethereum.org/ and load the source code.
3. Go to RUN (next to compile tab on top right) tab on remix.
4. Choose the environment as Injected Web3, and then select the account in the dropdown below. If the account not shown ensure step 1 is done, and then refresh the page.
5. Set the Gas limit to 6000000, keep value 0 as you are not going to send any ether
6. Select the contract function name in the drop-down in the next group
7. Paste the contract address in "Load Contract From Address" and then click "At Address" next to it.
8. Your functions will then be listed, select the function `drop` you can paste your parameters like `"TOKEN_ADDR",["ADDR1","ADDR2"],[500,700]`
9. Click on the button next to the parameter, metamask will now ask for your confirmation
10. Once confirmed the transaction will be submitted.

Comment: thank you very much/ iam trying it, and will it cost me so much ether ?

Comment: The metamask will calculate the Gas Limit automatically based on your array size. You are allowed to change the Gas Price, however, the bigger you keep, the sooner your transactions will get mined.

Comment: hello again / i have a problem with the execution of the airdrop check it here : http://prntscr.com/hte3sc (screenshot) it says that unexpected end of jason input / plus how can i define how much to send to each adresse / example i want to send 1 token or 2 per each adresse so how !! thank you

Comment: You have not seems to have filled the parameters for the drop function. Check Point 8 of above, and fill them accordingly before clicking the drop button. Since you pass two arrays, the number of items in the arrays should be same. that means address on index `n` will receive `n`th index number of tokens from array2.

Comment: hello thnx again ! i have filled the drop function but still the same error !! i dont know what is the problem !!

Comment: JSON related error use to appear when the address types are not enclosed with double quotes. Did you fill them properly?

Comment: please give me the formula so i can try again / can you give me an example thank you so much / i did this one that you gave me but there is a problem !! "TOKEN_ADDR",["ADDR1","ADDR2"],[500,700]

Comment: check this : prntscr.com/httefe / do you have a twitter  please i want to contact you (via dm's) if you want / thnx :

Comment: This depends upon the number of items that you are trying to send. 150 items if arrays shall do it perfectly. It may allow upto 174 though, but 150 items is nominal.

Comment: im stuck / i dont know whats missing

Comment: whats the error now?